# Kylin start fail java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find metadata store by url: kylin_metadata@hbase

Tags: kylin

[image]

I install kylin by https://github.com/cas-packone/ambari-kylin-service/

```
2020-01-13 01:52:16,673 INFO  [main] utils.Compatibility:41 : Running in ZooKeeper 3.4.x compatibility mode
2020-01-13 01:52:16,710 INFO  [main] imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl:284 : Starting
2020-01-13 01:52:16,715 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper:438 : Initiating client connection, connectString=node1:2181 sessionTimeout=120000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@6c000e0c
2020-01-13 01:52:16,717 INFO  [main-SendThread(node1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn:1013 : Opening socket connection to server node1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-01-13 01:52:16,719 INFO  [main-SendThread(node1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn:856 : Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:49768, server: node1/127.0.0.1:2181
2020-01-13 01:52:16,721 INFO  [main-SendThread(node1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn:1273 : Session establishment complete on server node1/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x16f798087cc03af, negotiated timeout = 60000
2020-01-13 01:52:16,722 INFO  [main] imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl:326 : Default schema
2020-01-13 01:52:16,725 DEBUG [main] util.ZookeeperDistributedLock:142 : 6521@node1 trying to lock /kylin/kylin_metadata/create_htable/kylin_metadata/lock
2020-01-13 01:52:16,730 INFO  [main-EventThread] state.ConnectionStateManager:237 : State change: CONNECTED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find metadata store by url: kylin_metadata@hbase
    at org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.createResourceStore(ResourceStore.java:89)
    at org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.getStore(ResourceStore.java:101)
    at org.apache.kylin.rest.service.AclTableMigrationTool.checkIfNeedMigrate(AclTableMigrationTool.java:94)
    at org.apache.kylin.tool.AclTableMigrationCLI.main(AclTableMigrationCLI.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.createResourceStore(ResourceStore.java:83)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.framework.api.CreateBuilder.creatingParentsIfNeeded()Lorg/apache/curator/framework/api/ProtectACLCreateModePathAndBytesable;
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.util.ZookeeperDistributedLock.lock(ZookeeperDistributedLock.java:145)
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.util.ZookeeperDistributedLock.lock(ZookeeperDistributedLock.java:166)
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.HBaseConnection.createHTableIfNeeded(HBaseConnection.java:305)
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.HBaseResourceStore.createHTableIfNeeded(HBaseResourceStore.java:110)
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.HBaseResourceStore.<init>(HBaseResourceStore.java:91)
    ... 8 more
2020-01-13 01:52:16,772 INFO  [Curator-Framework-0] imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl:924 : backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2020-01-13 01:52:16,773 INFO  [Thread-1] zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient:344 : Close zookeeper connection 0x7b94089b to node1:2181
2020-01-13 01:52:16,775 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-node1:2181@0x7b94089b] zookeeper.ZooKeeper:692 : Session: 0x16f798087cc03ae closed
2020-01-13 01:52:16,775 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-node1:2181@0x7b94089b-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn:517 : EventThread shut down
2020-01-13 01:52:16,777 INFO  [Thread-4] zookeeper.ZooKeeper:692 : Session: 0x16f798087cc03af closed
2020-01-13 01:52:16,777 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn:517 : EventThread shut down
ERROR: Unknown error. Please check full log.
```

Comment: `kylin_metadata@hbase` make sure your hbase is valid

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. Please help.